# Blank Laptop Screen after ram upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenevo ideapad S340-14IIL (81VV) i3 1005g1 which came with a 4GB 2666MHZ DDR4 ram soldered into the motherboard and another 4GB 2666MHZ DDR4 SODIMM Ram which is removable, I put a 16GB 2666MHZ DDR4 SODIMM and my laptop doesn't boot up, it just shows a black screen with power light ON, but when I remove the 16GB ram it boots up normally. I've tried removing the battery and then installing the ram but it doesn't work. I've also checked with max supported ram with the command wmic memphysical get maxcapacity, which returned a value of 32GB. I'd be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Did you check compatibility first, before buying? The detail you provided is not sufficient for accurate specification. See  https://uk.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/ideapad-s340-14iil btw, it can only take 20GB not 32, because the first 4 is soldered.

Comment: Yes i did run the compatibility test and bought the ram with same specifications as shown on the crucial website. I'm trying to put in a 16gb stick so it'll only be 20gb(16+4)

Comment: I'd get back to the seller then. It may be faulty.

Comment: I've also tried to put that ram in a different laptop and it went blank too